# how to set dropdownlist selected value inside a Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

i have a dropdownlist inside a grid view. here is the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFabricDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="49px" onrowdatabound="gvFabricDetails_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Programme">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgramme" DataTextField="PROGRAMME_NAME" DataValueField="PROGRAMME_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PROGRAMME") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lot/Style">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLot" TabIndex="2" Text='<%# Bind("LOT_STYLE") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Art#">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtArt" TabIndex="3" Text='<%# Bind("ART") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code behind to bind the data

```
public DataTable loadFabricInfos()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "";

    sql = "SELECT PROGRAMME,LOT_STYLE,ART FROM FABRICISSUE";

    OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(sql);
    OracleDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
    using (OracleConnection strConn = GetConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            objCommand.Connection = strConn;
            strConn.Open();
            objDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            strConn.Close();
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

now the problem is other textbox inside gridview is getting data. but the dropdown list is not bind with the database data. `SelectedValue` property is giving error like:

`DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PROGRAMME'.`

Comment: where are you binding the dropdown list?

Comment: i have done that in Gridview_RowDataBound event

Comment: You have to first bind dropdownlist datasource after that you can set selectedvalue

Comment: But i do not have any datasource. i am binding dropdown with a datatable which is coming from sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Bind it into the radgrid Itemdatabond event in code behind:

```
private void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item is GridDataItem)) {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item;
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlProgramme");
        list.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(item.DataItem, "<Datafield_name>").ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps...

Answer (score 2):

Change This Line
Your Query is SELECT **PROGRAMME**,**LOT_STYLE**,**ART** FROM FABRICISSUE

You should use the fields Of Your Query Like

DataTextField="**LOT_STYLE**" DataValueField ="**PROGRAMME**"  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("**PROGRAMME**") %>'

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgramme" DataTextField="PROGRAMME_NAME" DataValueField="PROGRAMME" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PROGRAMME") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Your solution is looking perfect. but the easy way to do    `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgramme" DataTextField="PROGRAMME_NAME" DataValueField="PROGRAMME_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PROGRAMME_ID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>` because if he changes the datavaluefield, he have to change datalayer or Sp. if PROGRAMME_ID is value field, then let it be and have to change it in the selectedvalue  area.

Comment: I have tried those ..but it does not work..thanks anyway